# How to get the value which is assigned in radio button?

Tags: java, swing, jradiobutton

I am trying to get the value from multiple radio button. This means whenever I select more than one button it should print that value. Suppose I select pizza and Burger after selecting that option and press the submit button it will print the value which is assigned in that button.

```java
package radio;

import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;

public class RadioButton extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {
    
    JRadioButton pizza;
    JRadioButton cabab;
    JRadioButton Burger;
    JButton button;
    ButtonGroup group;
    
    RadioButton() {      
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        button = new JButton();
        button.setText("Submit");
        button.setFocusable(false);
        
        button.addActionListener(this);
        
        pizza = new JRadioButton("Pizza");
        cabab = new JRadioButton("cabab");
        Burger = new JRadioButton("Burger");
         
        pizza.setFocusable(false);
        cabab.setFocusable(false);
        Burger.setFocusable(false);
        
        this.add(button);
        this.add(pizza);
        this.add(cabab);
        this.add(Burger);
        this.setVisible(true);
        this.pack();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (pizza.isSelected() &&  e.getSource() == button) {
            System.out.println("Pizza is selected");
        }
        else if (cabab.isSelected() && e.getSource() == button) {
            System.out.println("Cababa is selected");
        }
        else if (Burger.isSelected() && e.getSource() == button) {
            System.out.println("Burger is selected");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Nothing is selected");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: replace ~else if~ statement with ~if~ statement

Comment: Users expect check boxes when selecting multiple items and radio buttons when making one choice from many.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you will only get one result printed, even if multiple radiobuttons are selected, because you have set up your evaluation code in the `actionPerformed` method in a single `if-else` block. So once one statement evaluates to `true`, the rest of the block is skipped.

So to fix this, you could actually check every `JRadioButton` in a single `if` statement as follows:

```
boolean selectionFound = false;
if (pizza.isSelected() &&  e.getSource() == button) {
    selectionFound = true;
    System.out.println("Pizza is selected");
}
if (cabab.isSelected() && e.getSource() == button) {
    selectionFound = true;
    System.out.println("Cababa is selected");
}
if (burger.isSelected() && e.getSource() == button) {
    selectionFound = true;
    System.out.println("Burger is selected");
}
if (!selectionFound) {
    System.out.println("Nothing is selected");
}
```

With this approach, every single selection is evaluated.
Also, if the only component that has registered this `ActionListener` is your button, you can omit the check for the source of the action.